# Table cannot be created

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have written this code, but still table can not be created in database. And just output is:

> "database created.... Sorry Table Not Created".

```
<?php                                   
    include 'connection.php';
    //Creating database
    $creatingdatabase = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS quest";
    $query1 = mysqli_query($con, $creatingdatabase);
    if($query1){ 

        echo "database created....";
        //creating tables
        $creatingtable = "CREATE TABLE quiz (
                        id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                        questions VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                        optiona VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                        optionb VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                        optionc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                        optiond VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
                        answer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
                                                )";
        $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $creatingtable);
        if($query2){echo "table created...";}
        else { echo "sorry... table not created"; }

    }
    else { echo "database can not be created"; }
?>
```

[image: This is the output as seen in the browser.]

Comment: Change 'else { echo "sorry... table not created"; }' to 'else { echo "sorry... table not created:".mysqli_error($con); }' so that we can see the error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CREATE TABLE` statement needs to specify the database to use, or you need to set the default database with `mysqli_select_db()`.

```
$creatingdatabase = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS quest";
$query1 = mysqli_query($con, $creatingdatabase);
mysqli_select_db($con, "quest");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'xxxxx';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE guest"; //Set name database here
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $conn =  mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,'guest');//Set name database here
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $query = "CREATE TABLE quiz (
        id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        questions VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        optiona VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        optionb VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        optionc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        optiond VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        answer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    )";
    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "Table users created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

But I'm not recommend user can create new database in your sql server.

> In terms of security, it's probably best to have a database already created and then simply add in the user data, even if it's the first record. Nothing is gained from a user being able to enter data into a web form and then indirectly running SQL code.